# AngularJS caching of ng-view templates (under MVC project) for offline?

Tags: angularjs, caching, typescript

Here is my new post: [AngularJS $templateCache under MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418596/angularjs-templatecache-under-mvc)

I have this routing set up in my MVC-Angular-TypeScript project:

```
export let app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize"]);

// Defined custom routes by using "ng-view" directive, 
// enable single page application (SPA) functionality

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // Templates for WorkOrderDetail
        .when("/", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Main", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/Forms", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Forms", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/Equipment", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Equipment", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/JobPlan", { templateUrl: "Template?name=JobPlan", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/AssetGroup", { templateUrl: "Template?name=AssetGroup", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/Documents", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Documents", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/History", { templateUrl: "Template?name=History", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/LabourAndMaterial", { templateUrl: "Template?name=LabourAndMaterial", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/Remedy", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Remedy", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/Cause", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Cause", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })

        // Templates for WorkOrderDetail Actions
        .when("/AddRemedyCause", { templateUrl: "Action?name=AddRemedyCause", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/AddResolutionNote", { templateUrl: "Action?name=AddResolutionNote", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ChangeLaborMaterial", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ChangeLaborMaterial", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ChangeStatus", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ChangeStatus", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ChangeWorkOrder", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ChangeWorkOrder", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/CompleteWorkOrder", { templateUrl: "Action?name=CompleteWorkOrder", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ExtendCompletionDate", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ExtendCompletionDate", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ReAssign", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ReAssign", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ReDispatch", { templateUrl: "Action?name=ReDispatch", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/UploadDocuments", { templateUrl: "Action?name=UploadDocuments", controller: "ActionController", controllerAs: "vm" })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

Is there any way to cache all these templates BEFORE the person with a tablet (accessing this web app) goes offline?

Its a SPA on a client side. So, if it goes offline, these templates will not load. I need to cache them before we go offline.

Any suggestions how to make this work, preload and cache all these templates? 
I need to enable offline capabilities for my app.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: True, please take a look at my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418596/angularjs-templatecache-under-mvc